# Get the average in a while loop

Tags: python, average

I am trying to get the average from my count. I don't know where to start, can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
i = 1
count = 0

#while loop to determine number of candy bars sold
while i < 5 :
    count += eval(input("How many candy bars did you sell in week "+str(i)+"? "))
    i+= 1

#print statements to return wanted info
print("Total number of candy bars sold in a month is: ",count)
```

Comment: To get average, you divide the sum of the values you want the average from by the number of values. So in this case, you're getting 4 values - perhaps make a variable like this: `average = count / 4`, or more programmatically, `average = count / (i-1)`, in case you want to average more than 4 weeks in the future.

Comment: @MichaelBonnet Thank you for helping a newbie! I tried that earlier and figured out it was where placed the variable that made a difference. I had the `avg = count / 4` below `count = 0`. I was getting 0.0. So I placed it where you showed me below and it worked!

Comment: Of course. For future reference, in most (all?) languages, the compiler/interpreter won't know that something has been updated "later" and use that update "earlier". Your program will flow in "chronological" order of how it is written. Computers will only check things when told to do so. And don't be discouraged by downvotes or whatever - I was once in your position. In an unrelated educational track learning Python for the hell of it and messing up. I'm now a software engineer for spacecraft. You got this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide the total by the number of weeks in a month (4):

```py
i = 1
count = 0

#while loop to determine number of candy bars sold
while i < 5 :
    count += eval(input("How many candy bars did you sell in week "+str(i)+"? "))
    i+= 1

#print statements to return wanted info
print("Total number of candy bars sold in a month is: ",count)

average = count / 4.0
print("The average number of candybars per week is:", average)
```